# C#: Conditional compilation error in jwplayer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, video, jwplayer

I am embedding jwplayer for my videos on a website.

Using `video.flash()` and `video.MediaPlayer()` from system assemblies in ASP.net MVC4 i was able to embed videos. I am trying `jwplayer` now for cool interface.

This is how the code looks like-

```
@model MvcApplication8.Models.SystemUser
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jwplayer('my-video').setup({
            file: @Model.FilePath,
            width: '770',
            height: '360'

        });
    });

</script>

<div id="my-video"></div>
```

But it is not showing video there, it is giving this error- "Condition compilation is turned off`.

Am i doing a mistake in embedding video through `jwplayer`?

What is this error about?

Comment: Can you provide a link? That error message is not from the JW Player though.

Comment: @EthanLongTail, Yeah it shouldn't be this, Can't give you link because the path is coming dynamically.

Comment: Can you put up anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found answer to this question.

Thanks @EthanLongTail for administrating jwplayer very well. I found this answer from one of answers you've given.

Chnaged the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jwplayer('my-video').setup({
            playlist: [{
                image: "/Images/bay.png",
                sources: [{
                    file: "@Model.FilePath"
                }]
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

That conditional compilation error didn't appear next time with this code. Because `FilePath` was coming dynamically so i couldn't share it properly.